# Checking for NULL values in grouping condition

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Starting from a relation R (A, B), I am trying to write a query selecting all the A-entries that do not have any corresponding NULL B-values and I get error: `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.` I tried fiddling with the paranthesis more, but it seems to be that `COUNT` and `IS NULL` cannot be used together. Can anyone suggest a clean alternative to this ? Thank you !

```
SELECT   A
FROM     R
GROUP BY A
HAVING   (COUNT (B IS NULL) = 0 );
```

Comment: if your doubt is only in using count() in the having clause try the below.
HAVING COUNT(B) = 0

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed all I needed, since COUNT doesn't take the NULL values into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the total count for every value of `A` with the count of the column `B` (which ignores `NULL` values.

```
SELECT   A
FROM     R
GROUP BY A
HAVING  COUNT(*) = COUNT(B)
```